# Save command line argument to variable and use a default if it is missing or invalid

Tags: rust

The idea here is simple but I have tried three different ways with different errors each time: read in a string as an argument, but if the string is invalid or the string isn't provided, use a default.

Can this be done using `Result` to detect a valid string or a panic?

The basic structure I expect:

```
use std::env;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = args().collect();
    let word: Result<String, Error> = &args[1].expect("Valid string");
    let word: String = match word {
        Ok(word) = word,
        Err(_) = "World",
    }
    println!("Hello, {}", word);
}
```

Comment: What counts as an invalid argument?

Comment: Why you make an assignation with `.expect` to a `Result` variable?, as i understand do you need to use `unwrap_or_default` when reading if exists any command line argument, and then verify if the argument is correct if not overwrite with default

Comment: You should probably make a custom type and implement `FromStr` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are a lot of issues in your code.

First and foremost, in a match statement, you do not use `=`, you use `=>`.
Additionally, your match statement returns something, which makes it not an *executing* block, but rather a *returning* block (those are not the official terms). That means that your blocks result is bound to a variable. Any such *returning* block must end with a semicolon.
So your match statement would become:

```rust
let word: String = match word {
    Ok(word) => word,
    Err(_) => ...,
};
```

Next, when you do `use std::env`, you do not import all of the functions from it into your namespace. All you do is that you create an alias, so that the compiler turns `env::<something>` into`std::env::<something>` automatically.

Therefore, this needs to be changed:

```rust
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
```

The same problem exists in your next line. What is `Error`? Well, what you actually mean is `io::Error`, that is also not imported due to the same reasons stated above. You might be wondering now, how `Result` does not need to be imported. Well, it is because the Rust Team has decided on a certain set of functions and struct, which are automatically imported into every project. Error is not one of them.

```rust
let word: Result<String, io::Error> = ...;
```

The next part is wrong twice (or even thrice).

First of all, the operation `[x]` does not return a Result, it returns the value and panics if it is out-of-bounds.

Now, even if it **was** a result, this line would still be wrong. Why? Because you `expect(...)` the result. That would turn **any** Result into its value.

Now, what you are looking for is the `.get(index)` operation. It tries to get a value and if it fails, it returns `None`, so it returns an option. What is an option? It is like a result, but there is no error value. It must be noted that `get()` returns the option filled with a reference to the string.

The line should look something like this:

```rust
let word: Option<&String> = args.get(1);
```

Now you have two options to handle default values, but before we come to that, I need to tell you why your error value is wrong.

In Rust, there are two kinds of Strings.

There is ´&str`, which you can create like this:

```rust
let a: &str = "Hello, World!";
```

These are immutable and non-borrowed strings stored on the stack. So you cannot just create a new one with arbitary values on the fly.

On the other hand, we have mutable and heap-allocated `String`s.

```rust
let mut a: String = String::new();
a.push_str("Hello, World!");
// Or...
let b: String = String::from("Hello, World");
```

You store your arguments as a `String`, but in your match statement, you try to return a `&str`.

So, there are two ways to handle your error:

```rust
let word: Option<&String> = args.get(1);
let word: String = match word {
    Some(word) => word.to_string(),
    None => String::from("World"),
};
```

If you do not want to allocate that second string, you can also use

```rust
let word: Option<&String> = args.get(1);
let word: &str = match word {
    Some(word) => word.as_str(),
    None => "World",
};
```

The second option, `unwrap_or`

```rust
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let default = &String::from("World");
let word: &String = args.get(1).unwrap_or(default);
println!("Hello, {}", word);
```

is a bit uglier, as it requires you to `bind` the default value to a variable. This will do what your match statement above does, but it's a bit prettier.

This works too:

```rust
let word: &str = args.get(1).unwrap_or(default);
```

So this is my favourite version of your program above:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let default = &String::from("World");
    let word: &str = args.get(1).unwrap_or(default);
    println!("Hello, {}", word);
}
```

But this one works too:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let word: Option<&String> = args.get(0);
    let word: &str = match word {
        Some(word) => word.as_str(),
        None => "World",
    };
    println!("Hello, {}", word);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. On the second version, I had to use args.get(1); to get the first string argument `cargo run -- test` -> Hello, test